# PS4 controller on PS3 not working

Tags: ps4, ps3, controllers

When I plug it into the PS3 it dosen't work/light up. Everywhere else it works, bluetooth also works. I have tried resetting the control via the thing in the back plugging it in and out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The PS4 DualShock controller cannot be connected to the PS3 through a wired connection, only through a bluetooth one. sorry.